# Android: Getting the Resource File from an App

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gimp

Is there anyway to get the resources from a packaged app from the app store. I see an app similar to one I want to make and would like to examine how they made an image in more details.

Thanks.

Comment: no you can't, unless the developer made the code public, in which case you'll have to search for it online.

Comment: @BillGary APK files are just zip files, (just like opendocument, ooxml, java jar files, python egg files and God knows which more)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you got the `apk` file and you want to get the images from that app or some source code you can give a try , first if you want an image  , change the file from .apk to .zip and open it then you can see the images , if you want the source code use a tool called `dex2jar` then use a decompiler to get the source code note that i may be obfuscated .